# Playing audio files in Django app?

Tags: html, django, audio

I have a Django app and I want to try to play a song on it. Before, I had this in my HTML:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">  
<source src="audio/song.ogg" />
```

where audio is a folder within my templates folder. This works when I just run the HTML file inside my browser, but it no longer works when I access the site from my Django server. If anyone has any help, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know :)

*settings.py*

```
MEDIA_URL = 'file_location'
```

*html*

```
<audio id="Player" autoplay>
     <source src="{{MEDIA_URL}}audio/song.ogg"/>
</audio>
```

Comment: So in this case, if my song location is mysite/myapp/templates/myapp/audio/song.ogg, MEDIA_URL = 'mysite/myapp/templates/myapp'?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. All I see is: MEDIA_URL = 'mysite/myapp/templates/myapp'

Comment: @user2253332 where you enter MEDIA_URL ?

Comment: I put it in settings.py now. However, in my source I get

<audio id="Player" autoplay>
    <source src="audio/song.ogg"/>
</audio>

instead of the media_url path.